# vertical scroll bar get disable and bounce back in iphone simulator using phone-gap

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, cordova

I am developing phonegap app in iphone,after successfully viewing **pdf** file
(from server) on new HTML page,the vertical scrollbar get disable ,even i get back to the
list page ,the list does not get scroll,this happen only if i run the app directly in
simulator (not from xcode),any one know ,how to resolve this issue.

thanks in advance.

regards,
mayur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display pdf in phonegap, have lots of trouble, but best solution so far,is to used ChildBrowser Plugin for phonegap here is the link- 
https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser

this will help you to call child native uiwebview in your application(only for iphone), so you can easily enjoy pinch zoom feature, even the app scrollbar does not get disable,
it works fine!